# import libtorrent not working

Tags: python, homebrew, libtorrent

I installed libtorrent-rasterbar on a mac with brew. After I installed I check if it was good installed with the command:

```
brew install libtorrent-rasterbar
```

And I get:
Warning: libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.10 already installed

So installation looks to be ok.

If I go to python and type "import libtorrent" y get an error.
Also if I type:

```
>>>help('modules')
```

I dont see libtorrent in the list.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Brew has nothing to do with Python. It'll just install system libraries. If you want to install libraries/modules for Python, you should use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (recommended) or easy_install.

I couldn't find very good Python support for libtorrent in particular, although there is great support for other torrent libraries like PyTorrent.

If you must use libtorrent-rasterbar, there's a great tutorial on how to do it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/549509/how-do-you-install-libtorrent-rasterbar-python-bindings-with-a-brewed-python)

Comment: How can I installa PyTorrent, with? I try "sudo easy_install /Users/jloubet/Downloads/PyTorrent-0.1.1-py2.5.egg" But I get a error (can't find the file).

Comment: @Tony by far the easiest way is use pip. `pip install PyTorrent` is all you need. It'll make installing packages for Python 1000x easier than whatever you're doing now.

Comment: Thank you Eli, I'm installed PyTorrent, now I trying how to use it!

Comment: Whoever downvoted: mind explaining why, so I can improve the answer? The OP seems happy with my answer, but if there's room for improvement, would be very curious to hear about it.